# Inserting values into a table based on column values of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I would like to insert data into a table based on all the values of a secondary table's column. For example

I have two tables

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
id int identity(1, 1) not null,
FullName varchar(100),
Age int,
CourseID int
```

)

```
CREATE TABLE Table2 (
id int identity(1, 1) not null,
Courses int
```

)

I would like to perform something like this ..

```
insert into Table1 ('Auser',20,'And the list of Courses that I get from Table2')
```

Is there a way I can do this in sql server ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So for one new user you want to insert all available courses?

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
   SELECT 'Ausser', 20, t2.Courses 
   FROM Table2 t2;
```

Edit: Here's the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89470/1/0

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use the [MERGE STATEMENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) . Here is a program for your example

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
(
    Id int identity(1, 1) not null,
    FullName varchar(100),
    Age int,
    CourseID int
)

CREATE TABLE Table2 
(
    ID int identity(1, 1) not null,
    Courses int
);

INSERT INTO Table2  
SELECT 10 UNION ALL SELECT 20 UNION ALL 
SELECT 30 UNION ALL SELECT 40 UNION ALL SELECT 50;

--The Merge Query
MERGE Table1 AS t1
USING (SELECT * FROM Table2) AS t2
ON t1.CourseID= t2.Courses
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(FullName,Age,CourseID)
VALUES('Ausser',20,t2.Courses);

SELECT *
FROM Table1

DROP TABLE Table1
DROP TABLE Table2
```

//Result

```
Id  FullName    Age CourseID
1   Ausser      20    10
2   Ausser      20    20
3   Ausser      20    30
4   Ausser      20    40
5   Ausser      20    50
```