# Concatenating data from multiple sources and inserting as one row into SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql

What would be the best technique to use to insert a row of data retrieved from multiple sources (including textbox, other SQL tables, etc) into another SQL table? Will I need to create an intermediate data structure or is there a way to do it using something like

```
INSERT INTO Proposal_listing
(company_name, project_name, status_proposal) 
SELECT(company_name, project_name, status_pipeline) 
FROM Project_Pipeline 
WHERE status_pipeline = 'Proposal Phase';
```

EDIT: For example, if I wanted to take columns A1, B1, C1 from table 1 and values from textbox.text, textbox2.text and insert into columns A2, B2, C2, D2, E2 from table 2.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried your sql? Yes, it's possible to insert from another table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290733/inserting-values-into-a-table-based-on-column-values-of-another-table/12290777#12290777

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about trying to integrate your textbox value into your SQL Query.  Something like this:

```
string commandText = @"Insert INTO MyTable (Column1, Column2, Column3)
                          SELECT FirstName, LastName, @TBValue
                          FROM OtherTable where id = @QSValue";
cmd.CommandText = commandText;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@TBValue", tb_MyBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@QSValue", Request.QueryString["id"]);
```

This is all off the top of my head so you might need to play with the syntax, but that's the general idea.